# Drawing image on device screen with Vuforia SDK

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I'm trying to make an application with vuforia sdk 2.9. I want to draw some images on top of my target but on screen not on world. How is that possible ?

Comment: If you've solved your problem please share the answer.

Comment: There was a method posted in the vuforia forums about how to get the projection of point in the world to the screen point. I used that method and got the projection of center of trackable in world on my screen, then i could do what i wanted to do.